# Continuity of the function $f(y)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} y\sin(x) e^{-xy} \, dx $ in $y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

How do you prove the continuity of the follow function in $y=0$

> $f:[0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(y) =\int_0^{+\infty} y\sin(x) e^{-xy} \, dx$

We change the variables: $x\rightarrow \frac {x}{y}$
So now we have:
$$f(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} \sin\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) e^{-x} \, dx $$

To prove the continuity, we take a row $y_n \rightarrow 0$. We can assume that $y_n>0$ for each $n$. Now we have to prove that
$f(y_n) \rightarrow 0$

Now we can apply the dominated convergence theorem with dominated function $e^{-x}$ but then I'm stuck.
(the change of variables was given as a hint). Can someone help me.

Comment: Integrating by parts to explicitly find the function $f(y)$ for $y>0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: You mean integrating by parts on $f(y_{n})$ and then take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty $ ? @Hetebrij

Comment: Well, for any $y>0$, you can use integrating by parts to obtain a 'value' of the integral, which gives $f(y)$ as normal function. Once you obtained this function, you see that the limit $f(y)$ of $y$ to $0$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$
f(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} \sin\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) e^{-x} \, dx =\int_0^{+\infty} \sin {(tx)} e^{-x} \, dx\to 0
$$
as $t\to \infty$ ($y\to 0$) by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which is proved in [How to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int_a^bf(t)\sin(xt)\,dt=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314138/how-to-prove-lim-limits-x-to-infty-int-abft-sinxt-dt-0/1315247#1315247).

Comment: Why is that last integral bounded as a function of $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you consider $$I=\int y\,\cos(x) e^{-xy} \, dx$$ $$J=\int y\,\sin(x) e^{-xy} \, dx$$ then $$I+iJ=\int y \,e^{-x (y-i)} \, dx=-\frac{y\, e^{-x (y-i)}}{y-i}$$ which makes $$I=\frac{y \,e^{-x y} (\sin (x)-y \cos (x))}{y^2+1}$$ $$J=-\frac{y \,e^{-x y} (y \sin (x)+\cos (x))}{y^2+1}$$ Then $$K=\int_0^\infty y\sin(x) e^{-xy} \, dx=\frac{y}{y^2+1}\qquad \Re(y)>0$$ $$L=\int_0^\infty y\cos(x) e^{-xy} \, dx=\frac{y^2}{y^2+1}\qquad \Re(y)>0$$